# suddenly UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey is unavailable

Tags: ios, ios9, ios9.1

I don't understand this. Suddenly, I couldn't use the in iOS 9.0 introduced UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey identifier for accessing text input messages in notifications. Xcode 7.1 says: "UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey is unavailable".

But I can see this value in UIUserNotificationeSettings.h.

In Watchos2.0 I have this value.

Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in the current Xcode 7.2 beta. And I have cleaned every temporary file in the DerivedData folder

Comment: 'UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNTextInputNotificationResponse userText]

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same exact thing in the release version of **Xcode 7.2**. Instead of using the key `UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey`, I've gotten it working using the string version "`UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey`".

So for me this is doing the trick:

```
if let response = responseInfo["UIUserNotificationActionResponseTypedTextKey"] as? String {
     // Your code here
}
```